# Conditions for solution to equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the following question in an exercise of linear fitting.
**Q.**
We have $n$ linearly independent known vectors $\textbf{a}_i$, $i = 1, . . . , n$, a known vector $\textbf{b}$, and an unknown vector $\textbf{x}$. All vectors are of dimension $m$. Under what conditions is there a solution to the following equation?
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \textbf{a}_i\textbf{a}_i^T \textbf{x}= \textbf{b}$$
Express in terms of $m$ and $n$.

---

**My attempt:**
Let $\textbf{A} = [\textbf{a}_1, ..., \textbf{a}_n]$, $m × n$ matrix.
So, $ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \textbf{a}_i\textbf{a}_i^T \textbf{x} =\textbf{A}\textbf{A}^T \textbf{x} =  \textbf{b}$.
Since $\textbf{a}_i$ are linearly independent vectors which form the columns of $\textbf{A}$, column rank of $\textbf{A}$ is $n$.
For equation $\textbf{A}\textbf{A}^T \textbf{x} =  \textbf{b}$, we have the following 3 cases considering the $m × m$ matrix $\textbf{A}\textbf{A}^T$:

**Case 1**: $m = n$
$rank(\textbf{A}) = n \implies rank(\textbf{A}\textbf{A}^T) = n = m$
So, $\textbf{A}\textbf{A}^T$ is a full rank matrix, hence, invertible. So the equation has a unique solution.

**Case 2**: $m > n$
$rank(\textbf{A}) = n \implies rank(\textbf{A}\textbf{A}^T) = n < m$
So, $\textbf{A}\textbf{A}^T$ is a rank deficient matrix. For a solution to exist, vector **b** must lie in the column space of matrix $\textbf{A}\textbf{A}^T$.

> (1) Can we express this in terms of $m$ and $n$?

**Case 3**: $m < n$
$rank(\textbf{A}) = n \implies rank(\textbf{A}\textbf{A}^T) = n > m$
This case of a matrix having a rank more than numbers of columns seems absurd generally.

> (2) But is it possible in linear fitting or in an overdetermined system, since we have more equations than unknowns?

> (3) What other conditions am I missing?

---

So, I am unable to answer the 3 open questions above. Kindly help me.

Comment: MSE is a right forum for such questions.

Comment: Thanks. I have moved the question to MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3827913/conditions-for-solution-to-equation)

Answer (score 2):

All the vectors are $\textit{m}$ - dimensional, so they lie in an $\textit{m}$ - dimensional space. You can only have at-most $\textit{m}$ linearly independent vectors in an $\textit{m}$ - dimensional space. So by definition, you only have 2 cases, $\textit{m}$ = $\textit{n}$ or $\textit{m}$ > $\textit{n}$.

case 1) When $\textit{m}$ = $\textit{n}$, your answer that the equation has a unique solution is accurate.

case 2) when $\textit{m}$ > $\textit{n}$, your answer that $\mathbf{b}$ must lie in the column space of $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^\intercal$ is accurate. I don't think this can be simplified any further in terms of $\textit{m}$ and $\textit{n}$ alone, as for any given $\textit{m}$ and $\textit{n}$, such that $\textit{m}$ > $\textit{n}$, you can always find a $\mathbf{b}$ vector that satisfies the equation, and several $\mathbf{b}$ vectors outside the column space which do not satisfy the equation. To solve the equation, you can project $\mathbf{b}$ onto the column space of $\mathbf{A}$, which gives you the nearest vector in the column space to the vector $\mathbf{b}$. More details on Projection matrices can be found [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/video-lectures/lecture-15-projections-onto-subspaces/) (Linear Algebra by Gilbert Strang).

Case 3) This is never possible as already explained. If $\mathbf{A}$ is $\textit{m}\times\textit{n}$ matrix, and $\textit{m}$ < $\textit{n}$, rank($\mathbf{A}$) can never be $\textit{n}$. It can be at-most $\textit{m}$ only.

I hope this helps.

Comment: You are fighting against TeX's carefully tuned formatting.  Don't use $\mathit{m}$ = $\mathit{n}$ `$\mathit{m}$ = $\mathit{n}$`, for example; use $m = n$ `$m = n$`.  It's simpler, more semantically correct, and turns out prettier, too.